# How do I compile my opencv program with g++ on windows?

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

When I try to compile my opencv loadimg.cpp program with

```
g++ -I "C:\opencv\opencv410x64\include" -L "C:/opencv/opencv410x64/x64/mingw/lib" loadimg.cpp  -libopencv_highgui410 -o loadimage
```

I get tihis message. what is wrong with this command..

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -libopencv_highgui410
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the GCC linkage option `-l<name>` requests the linker to find a file in one of its search directories
with one of the names:

```
lib<name>.a
<name>.lib
<name>.dll
```

and then link your program against that library. So your option `-libopencv_highgui410`
requests the linker to find one of the files:

```
libibopencv_highgui410.a
ibopencv_highgui410.lib
ibopencv_highgui410.dll
```

which certainly don't exist. Assuming that one of files `libopencv_highgui410.a`, `opencv_highgui410.lib` or `opencv_highgui410.dll`
exists in `C:/opencv/opencv410x64/x64/mingw/lib` or in a default linker search directory, use

```
-lopencv_highgui410
```

instead.

Comment: `libopencv_highgui410.dll.a` file exist in `C:/opencv/opencv410x64/x64/mingw/lib` . May be I misunderstood about dynamic linking on gcc.